# Can I create the variables and launch the methods of my classes in PowerShell hosted by me?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-hosting

PowerShell 4.0

I want to host PowerShell engine in my application and to have the capability of using API of my application in the hosted PowerShell. I read the description of the [PowerShell class](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and its [members](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell_members%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the documentation. In the `PowerShell.exe` and `PowerShell_ISE.exe` hosts I can to create the variables, loops, launch the static and instance methods of my classes. Can I do the same through the `PowerShell` class? I can't find the the examples about it.

It is my simple attempt to do it:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace MyPowerShellApp {

    class User {
        public static string StaticHello() {
            return "Hello from the static method!";
        }
        public string InstanceHello() {
            return "Hello from the instance method!";
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
                ps.AddCommand("[MyPowerShellApp.User]::StaticHello");
                // TODO: here I get the CommandNotFoundException exception
                foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke()) {
                    Console.WriteLine(result.Members.First());
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key for exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You need to make `User` class public, to be visible to PowerShell.
2. You should use `AddScript` instead of `AddCommand`.

This code will call two methods of `User` class and print resulting strings to console:

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace MyPowerShellApp {

    public class User {
        public static string StaticHello() {
            return "Hello from the static method!";
        }
        public string InstanceHello() {
            return "Hello from the instance method!";
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
                ps.AddScript("[MyPowerShellApp.User]::StaticHello();(New-Object MyPowerShellApp.User).InstanceHello()");
                foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke()) {
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key for exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```